# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar cada elemento del arreglo en un div diferente?

Tags: javascript

Necesito mostrar los elementos de un arreglo en un div distinto utilizando foreach necesariamente.

```
const usuario = ["Elena", "Juan", "Raul","Wendy","Renzo"]
   const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div")
   divs.forEach(function(item, indice) {
   item.innerHTML = item + indice
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Realizado de este modo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        div:nth-child(even){
          background-color: red;
        }
        div:nth-child(odd){
          background-color: steelblue;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      
    </div>
    <script>
      const usuario = ["Elena", "Juan", "Raul","Wendy","Renzo"]
      
    
      
      usuario.forEach(function(element, index){
         let div = document.createElement('div')
             div.textContent = element
         
         document.body.appendChild(div)
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Explicación**

- Iteramos el arreglo por medio de un `forEach()`
- creamos un nuevo elemento `div` dentro del DOM con `createElement`
- Usamos `textContent` para establecer el texto de los nodos creados, en este caso el valor es `element` que será el texto de cada posición del `array`
- Finalmente con `appendChild` agregamos los nodos creados a la etiqueta `body` pasando como argumento la variable `div`
- Los estilos aplicados son solo para comprobar la creación de los elementos `div` con el valor de cada posición del arreglo
- Es mejor que los `divs` sean dinámicos, es decir que se vayan creando dentro del `forEach()` a medida que existan elementos del arreglo que deban ser acomodados en cada uno